# Convergence by using Cauchy Criterion

Tags: convergence-divergence

this is the sequence:

$(a_n)=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{1}{2n}$

And this is what I tried to do so far:

$|a_{n+1} - a_{n} | = \frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$
in order to show (hopefully?) that the sequence IS convergent, since it is (hopefully) a Cauchy-Sequence.

However, as you can see, I don't know if a) I'm on the right way, b) what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$${1\over n + k} \ge \int_{n+k}^{n+k+1}{dx\over x}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n {1\over n + k} \ge \sum_{k=0}^n\int_{n+k}^{n+k+1}{dx\over x}
= \int_{n}^{2n}{dx\over x} = \log(2).$$
Another similar inequality lurks.  You can show this, in fact, converges, and that it is therefore Cauchy.

Comment: hey, is there a second option without integral?

Comment: Likely, but it would involve some moderately arcane analytical trickery.  I can't think of one off-hand.

Comment: how the first inequality you got?

Comment: Look at the graph of $x\mapsto 1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $ 0 \le a_{n+1} - a_n , a_n \le 1 ( \forall n \in N ) $, use the Monotone Convergence Theorem.